# Написать функцию, которая возвращает сумму кодов букв слов, начинающихся с согласных

Tags: c++

Есть задача,которая возвращает сумму код первых букв слова, если они начинаются с согласных.
  Не подскажите, как переделать, чтобы возвращалась сумма кода Всех букв слов, 
если слово начинается с согласной

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

int func(char* str, char* dest, int size, int& sum, const std::string symb)
 {
int spaceCount = 0;
int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
        spaceCount++;

    if (i == 0 && str[i] != ' ')
    {
        dest[index] = str[i];
        index++;

    }

    if (i > 0 && spaceCount > 0)
    {
        dest[index] = str[i + 1];
        index++;
        spaceCount = 0;
    }
}
dest[index] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dest); i++)
{
    bool isNotInList = true;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < symb.size(); j++)
    {
        if (symb[j] == dest[i])
        {
            isNotInList = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isNotInList)
    {
        sum += dest[i];
    }

}
return sum;
}

int main()
{
int sum = 0;
char str[255] = { 0 };

    std::cout << "Enter string " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(str, 255);
    int size = strlen(str) + 1;

    char* dest = new char[size];

   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        dest[i] = 0;

   func(str, dest, size, sum, "aeiouyAEIOUY"); 
   std::cout << dest << std::endl;
   std::cout << sum << std::endl;
   delete[] dest;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: обьекту  `std::string`   можно присвоить С _ строку... Я к тому, что если  один из ваших аргументов   `std::string`, то зачем вы усложняете свой код, передав остальные строки  по указателью?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на `С++`, то уж без указателей можно. Что нужно сделать?

1. Сначала написать предикат, который проверяет, является ли первая
   буква слова согласной буквой?
2. Разделять строку на лексемы(слова), и если наш предикат по этим
   словам возвращает истину, то добавить к сумме(изначальна она
   нулевая) сумму целочисленных значений всех букв.

Для  вывода и программа не нужна:

```
using std::string;
static const string vowels("aeiouyAEIOUY");
bool is_consonant(const char c)
{
    return vowels.find(c) == string::npos;
}
int sum(const string& source)
{
    std::istringstream is(source);
    int x{};
    string s;   
    while (is >> s) {
        //если первая буква не гласная
        if (is_consonant(s[0])) 
            for (const char c : s)
                x += c;

    }
    return x;
}
std::ostream& os = std::cout << sum("test Abs efg");

int main() { return 0;}
```

**UPDATE:**

Я бы просто написал программу такую:

```
using std::string;
using In = std::istream_iterator<string>;   
std::cout << std::accumulate(In(std::cin), In(), int(),
    [](int x, const string& s)
    {
        if (vowels.find(s[0]) == string::npos)
            for (const char c : s)
                x += c;
        return x;
    });
```

Если уж нужно проверять есть ли в слове неправильные(не нужные нам символы), то нужно вспомнить, что еще нужно определять какие символы мы считаем лишные в слове... Но об этом в вопросе не было речи.

Comment: Ну а если строка "test!, Abs& efg#&" ? или "test. Abs. efg." То как мы с Вами уже говорили, подготовка данных - важная часть ) Ну и в is fatal бы не мешало бы обработать) Во всем остальное - такая же логика, как я предлагал несколько ранее в своем ответе)))

Comment: По поводу производительности - да Ваше решение быстрее на 25-30%, но выполняет меньше задач)) Вы сказали что Ваше решение будет проще, где оно проще, если реализует ту же логику я не пойму)))

Comment: @Maggot,  Читайте обнавленную часть.  А кто сказал, что эти символы лишные? Кто определил вообше что  такое слово и что в нем не правильно. Для разных языков и для разных профессий слова разные...

Comment: это старый спор ))) мы же с Вами так и не пришли к знаменателю. По поводу кто решил - решил я, знаки препинания не части слова )))

Comment: логика обновлённой версии ничем не отличается от старой ) вообщем логика проще - это все та же логика в другой обертке )))) вообщем каждый пишет сам как хочет ))))

Comment: Ладно,  не будем разворачиваться комментариями, но разница есть опять же...  Настаивать на своем _ это хорошо, но иногда мешает признать лучшее. Я ни на чем не настаиваю, может вы  и правы...

Comment: Ваш ответ лучший в одном плане со своими фишками, мой в другом со своими фишками ) задача решена  ) мы оба молодцы xD

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм

1. Берете строку и подготавливайте ее

   1.1 строку надо оттримировать(убрать мульти пробелы, пробелы в начале строки и в ее конце)

   1.2 выкосить все знаки пунктуации (.,/-/* и тд)

   1.3 сдампить в контейнер по словам (разбить на лексемы)

Дальше вариантов много - вот 2, что первые пришли в голову

2. Перебирая элементы контейнера, применить к первому символу слова

   2.1 проверку на первый элемент через find в векторе с гласными буквами, если она там нашлась - то начиниется с гласной, если не - то нет)

   2.2 регулярку rgx{"[aeiouyAEIOUY]"}; если проверка не прошла (просто гласных меньше - меньше регулярка)))) ), то через std::accumulate(std::begin(word), std::end(word), 0) посчитать сумму кодов символов данного слова и все это прибавить к накопительной сумме)

Вот пример кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <regex>
#include <cctype>


static std::regex rgx{"[aeiouyAEIOUY]"};


std::string trim(std::string str, bool multi_space = true) {

    auto trim_left_it{std::find_if(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](char ch){return !std::isspace(ch);})};
    str.erase(std::begin(str), trim_left_it);

    auto trim_right_it{std::find_if(std::rbegin(str), std::rend(str), [](char ch){return !std::isspace(ch);})};
    str.erase(trim_right_it.base(), std::end(str));

    if (multi_space) {
        std::string res;
        std::unique_copy(std::begin(str), std::end(str),
                        std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>(res),
                        [](char a,char b){ return isspace(a) && isspace(b);});
        return res;
    }

    return str;
}


std::string ClearPunctuationMarks(std::string str) {

    str.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(str), std::end(str), ispunct), std::end(str));

    return str;
}


std::vector<std::string> split_str(const std::string& str) {

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::size_t prev = 0, pos = 0;

    do {
        pos = str.find(' ', prev);
        if (pos == std::string::npos) {
            pos = str.length();
        }
        std::string token = str.substr(prev, pos-prev);
        if (!token.empty()) {
            tokens.push_back(token);
        }
        prev = pos + 1;
    } while (pos < str.length() && prev < str.length());

    return tokens;
}


uint64_t SumOfStartVowelsWord(std::string line) {

    uint64_t ret{0};

    auto v_word{split_str(line)};

    for (auto word : v_word) {
        if (!std::regex_match(word.substr(0,1), rgx)) {
            ret += std::accumulate(std::begin(word), std::end(word), 0);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


uint64_t SumOfStartVowelsWord2(std::string line) {

    uint64_t ret{0};

    auto v_word{split_str(line)};

    std::vector<char> v_char{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'};

    for (auto word : v_word) {
        if (std::find(std::begin(v_char), std::end(v_char), word[1]) != std::end(v_char)) {
            ret += std::accumulate(std::begin(word), std::end(word), 0);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


int main() {

    std::string line{"test, Abs! efg"};

    auto count{SumOfStartVowelsWord(ClearPunctuationMarks(trim(line)))};

    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    auto count2{SumOfStartVowelsWord2(ClearPunctuationMarks(trim(line)))};

    std::cout << count2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Столько возьни из за какой то ерунды?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну так) можно конечно сразу через сплит делать там будет 4 строчки, но не интересно )))

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы считаете, что подготовка данных к обработке пустое занятие?

Comment: я считаю, что когда можно сделать просто, не стоит делать сложно, что когда пишешь код, нужно стараться, чтобы он работал  как можно быстрее, как можно меньше памяти занимал и, насколько можно, обеспечить хорошую читабельность.  Эта задача слышком простая. Я напишу пример, не буду утверждать, что нельзя проще, но  вы сами можете оценить насколько проще по сравнению с вашим.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я согласен - меньше кода меньше проблем, можно решить в 8 строк. Но все же я говорю о подготовке данных которая нужна для корректной их обработки тут то сама функция 6 строк, и да 3 доп функции для подготовки данных. Корректность данных всяко важнее. Имхо это не критично.

Comment: корректность данных важна, иначе UB,  не об этом речь.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я понимаю о чем вы. Да можно сделать все проще без особого дёрганья stl обильного выделения памяти и тд) но разница минимальна, тем более есть большая вероятность, что большая часть кода что тут, что в Вашем решении будет сгенерированная и оптимизирована одинаково)

Comment: а вы берите и сравните ассемблер двух кодов и сравните быстродействие.  Компилятор оптимизирует, но не переделовает код... Ну, если вы не согласны,  это ваше право...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я не так выразился. На современных компиляторах если сложность алгоритма одинакова. разница не будет.

Answer (score -2):

Особо не тестил:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int func(char* str, char* dest, int size, int& sum, const std::string symb)
{
    int index = 0;
    bool spaceCount = true;
    bool wordFinded = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (spaceCount == true && wordFinded == false)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < symb.size(); j++)
            {
                if (symb[j] == str[i])
                {
                    wordFinded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            spaceCount = false;
        }

        if (wordFinded == true && str[i] != ' ')
        {
            dest[index++] = str[i];
            sum += str[i];
        }

        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            spaceCount = true;
            wordFinded = false;
        }
    }
   
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    char str[255] = { 0 };

    std::cout << "Enter string " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(str, 255);
    int size = strlen(str) + 1;

    char* dest = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        dest[i] = 0;

    func(str, dest, size, sum, "aeiouyAEIOUY");
    std::cout << dest << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    delete[] dest;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Может быть подойдёт так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isVowel(int ch)
{
    const auto vowelList = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'};
    return std::find(vowelList.begin(), vowelList.end(), ch) != vowelList.end();
}

int getSumOfCode(const std::string& line)
{
    int sum=0;
    bool isWord=false;
    bool isNeedSum=false;
    bool isFirtsChar=true;

    for(auto ch : line) {
        if(ch==' ') {
            isWord = false;
            isNeedSum = false;
            isFirtsChar = true;
        }
        else {
            isWord = true;
            if(isFirtsChar) {
                isFirtsChar = false;
                if(isVowel(toupper(ch))) {
                    isNeedSum = false;
                    continue;
                }
                else isNeedSum = true;
            }
            if(isNeedSum) sum+=ch;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Enter string: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << "Sum: " << getSumOfCode(line) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```